# Features and label size crashes (tflearn)

Tags: python, tensorflow, scikit-learn, kaggle, tflearn

I am playing with tflearn with pokemon kaggle dataset. 
I tried to put the Names of the pokemon as word2vec and the rest as normal matrix.
I am trying to preprocess the data.
[image]

What I did was change the Name to vector using TF learn

```
word_processor = VocabularyProcessor(100)
trainX = newDF.loc[:, ["Total","HP","Attack","Defense","Sp. Atk", "Sp. Def","Speed","Generation"]].as_matrix()
trainY = np.array(list(word_processor.fit_transform(newDF["Name"])))
trainY[None : 0]
print('shape trainX: ',trainX.shape)
print('shape train Y: ',trainY.shape)
```

The print statement shows
`shape trainX:  (800, 8)`
`shape train Y:  (800, 100)`
So I think this is the problem since when I am trying to feed this data to my neural network it shows.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-53-78ce72c15f14> in <module>()
      3 # Start training (apply gradient descent algorithm)
      4 # Training
----> 5 model.fit(trainX, trainY, validation_set=0.1, show_metric=True, batch_size=100, n_epoch=8)

/anaconda/envs/MLHardCore/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tflearn/models/dnn.py in fit(self, X_inputs, Y_targets, n_epoch, validation_set, show_metric, batch_size, shuffle, snapshot_epoch, snapshot_step, excl_trainops, validation_batch_size, run_id, callbacks)
    181         # TODO: check memory impact for large data and multiple optimizers
    182         feed_dict = feed_dict_builder(X_inputs, Y_targets, self.inputs,
--> 183                                       self.targets)
    184         feed_dicts = [feed_dict for i in self.train_ops]
    185         val_feed_dicts = None

/anaconda/envs/MLHardCore/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tflearn/utils.py in feed_dict_builder(X, Y, net_inputs, net_targets)
    281                 X = [X]
    282             for i, x in enumerate(X):
--> 283                 feed_dict[net_inputs[i]] = x
    284         else:
    285             # If a dict is provided

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Here is the neural network just incase

```
def NN():
    net = tflearn.input_data(shape=[None, 8])
    net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 32)
    net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 32)
    net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 2, activation='softmax')
    net = tflearn.regression(net)
    model = tflearn.DNN(net)
    return model

model = NN()

model.fit(trainX, trainY, validation_set=0.1, show_metric=True, batch_size=100, n_epoch=8)
```

Another new Error, after I restarted python.

```
Exception in thread Thread-6:
 line 187, in slice_array
    return X[start]
IndexError: index 359 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 100
```

Comment: I'm having a similar issue - just wanted to note that the there's an issue filed with tflearn, should that thread be updated: https://github.com/tflearn/tflearn/issues/637

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting the kernel and clear output  and to run it again .
I too faced this issue and this solution worked for me .